# Invalid CSRF token Symfony 5.4

Tags: php, symfony, token, csrf

I have a Symfony 5.4, in dev env (docker) the login works fine. But when I try the same login via docker on prod, i have :

```
{"message":"Invalid CSRF token."}
```

AppAuthenticator.php

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
.....
return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($credentials['username']),
            new PasswordCredentials($credentials['password']),
            [new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token'])]
        );
}
```

security.yaml

```
security:
  firewalls:
    main:
       form_login:
          login_path: _security_login
          check_path: _security_check
          enable_csrf: true
```

login.html.twig

```
<form method="post">
   ....
   <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}" />
</form>
```

Comment: I dont see the `action` of the form ( `action="{{ path('login') }}"` )

Comment: fixed here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/44541

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$credentials['csrf_token']` is equal to `$request->request->get('_csrf_token')`.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.